# Example ontology for the medical domain

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, owl, protege

I am searching for a clear example ontology respective to the medical domain. Maybe to show some reasoning. Or has anyone a good idea for a small medical example which I can implement with Protégé?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Gene Ontology](http://www.geneontology.org/) is a good representation of the biomedical domain. [Here](http://www.geneontology.org/GO.ontology.relations.shtml) you can find detailed examples to implement with Protege.

You could also have a look at the [Foundational Model](http://fme.biostr.washington.edu/FME/index.html) for the anatomy of the body.

If you are looking for a straightforward hierarchy/controlled vocabulary, you could look at [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/meddocs.html).

Answer (score 2):

The disease ontology : http://www.disease-ontology.org/

you'll also find a bunch of biology-releated ontologies at: http://bioportal.bioontology.org/

Answer (score 1):

[GALEN](http://www.opengalen.org/) is an expressive OWL ontology describing medical concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Some videos about developing ontologies for medical domain can be found here:
http://ontology.buffalo.edu/smith/